# how to POST relationships in STRAPI

Tags: http-post, strapi

Here's a newbie question for strapi but I haven't found it covered anywhere.

I have a ecommerce database and I would like to migrate my data to strapi. I managed to http post new items into the database but I dont know how to post the relationships. For example I managed to create a product via POST but I have no idea how to post its relationship with the manufacturer model.

Thanks.

I figured it out:

I just had to set a field with the name of the relation and the value of the related model's id. For some reason it haven't worked when I first tried this.